# secured way to update docker-compose project from web-interface of the container in this compoer

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, devops

I have a small docker-compose project (3 containers - nginx, python, postgres).  I want to have "update" button in the web-interface which will pull code from the repo, rebuild and restart containers if it's necessary. As I see, I can connect docker.sock to the container, but it isn't a secure way. Are there any alternative solutions for that?

Comment: https://tilt.dev/ can do this kind of thing automatically without needing to click a button.

Comment: A more typical practice would be to configure a _continuous integration_ system, so that when you commit code to source control, the CI system builds a Docker image, then triggers a redeployment.  Putting an "update" button in a UI like this is pretty unusual, especially in Docker.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm talking not about dev/test/local environment. It's a self-hosted application in docker-compose in a perimeter where I don't have access to. The idea is to give a software bundle, make it self-deployed with a single script in the terminal and get updates when the end-user/client/customer wants to instal updates and when they are available. I know about CI/CD tools, but as I said - it isn't a solution in this situation.

Comment: If you are familiar with Countly - count.ly 
They have similar things. If you want it self-hosted - there is 1 line of code you need to paste into the command line interface. And the solution is ready to go. And if you want to update the solution - you could press the "update" button in the web interface and that's it.

Comment: @DFe please [edit] your question with clarifying information instead of "hiding" it in the comments where people might not see it. Note that in general, [recommendations for software are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you think your requirements are on-topic, [edit] to explain how.